# Get TypeError when using TfidfVectorizer in python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I'm new to python and I'm needing your help.

I'm working with NLP, and I want to classify a field that is string.

I read the dataset

```py
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv",sep=';',encoding='latin-1',error_bad_lines=False)
```

tokenize the field

```py
data['campo']= data['campo'].str.split()
```

the output is:

```
1- [Su, inexperto, personal] 2- [Atención, al, cliente]
```

when I check tutorials that exist on the internet, to the majority, when tokeniza returns the separated words with apostrophe.

[image]

the problem is when I want to vectorize (`TfidfVectorizer`), I get an error and I think my problem is here.

Can you help me? Why do not I have the tokens with apostrophe?

After executing this, I add the possibility to vectorize the field:

```py
Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer (max_features = 5000)
Tfidf_vect.fit(data ['field'])
```

From here, I throw the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

I thought I was coming for the subject of the lower, so I added:

```py
Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer (lowercase = False, max_features = 5000)  

Tfidf_vect.fit (data ['field'])
```

and from there he shoots me:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Do you know what it is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do not tokenize your text before feeding into `tfidfVectorizer()`, which means you have to remove the following line in your code.

```
data['campo']= data['campo'].str.split()
```

TfidfVectorizer internally does the tokenization. Try your following lines of code directly!

```
Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer (max_features = 5000)
Tfidf_vect.fit(data ['campo'])
```